# Client cookie expiration not being set with UseTokenLifetime as true

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect

I have a client integrated with my `idsrv` instance. In the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` I have `UseTokenLifetime = true`. Even with this being so, when I check the cookie expiration in the browser for the client, the cookie is being set as `expires = session`. Could something be interfering with setting the cookie expiration to the same value as the `IdentityTokenLifetime (36000)`? Is this not the behavior I should expect (sorry if I'm looking at this incorrectly)?

Also, in case it's worth noting, the client is configured with a Hybrid flow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identity Server 3 User Session Lifetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363659/identity-server-3-user-session-lifetime)

Comment: @Venky nope, that's for the cookie on the idsrv site