# Asp.net Core 2 with IdentityServer4 - Redirect to Login after cookie expiration

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, identityserver4

I have an Asp.net Core 2.2 MVC application that authenticates using an IdentityServer4 server.
It is configured as you can see on the bottom, with really short times for quick testing.

The desired behavior is:

- Login (suppose without the "remember me checked")
- Do things...
- Wait until the session expires
- On the next navigation click redirect on the login page for a new interactive sign-in

I supposed I must work on cookies and session server side, but my first doubt is that I have to work more with id_token.

Anyway the current behavior is:

- Login without the "remember me checked"
- Wait until the session expires
- Click on a dummy page and I see that the session is empty (as expected) -> The login is available on the top menu
- So I click on login -> **No login page showed** -> a new session server side is available and in the browser there is a new value of ".AspNetCore.Cookies" but the same for ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" and "idsrv.session".

If I logout, the cookie client side is correctly removed, so at the next login shows the expected credential form.

What I'm doing wrong? 
Is it correct to try to get a new interactive sign-in checking the cookie expiration?
Do I have to follow another way working on the ids (id_token) objects?

**CODE**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
    {
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentitySettings:Authority");
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ClientId = "mvc";
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.Events.OnTicketReceived = async (context) =>
        {
            context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30);
        };
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsStaging())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

The logout is done as following

```
public async void OnPost()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");

    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc",
        new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002"
        });
}
```

Comment: Its because the cookie on idsrv4 hasn’t expired so its working as expected even though the cookie on your mvc app expired.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius, I am facing a similar issue with IdSvr3. How do we expire or invalidate cookie at IdSvr? I have assigned 120 (seconds) to all lifetime periods on IdSvr's client configuration. Even if we try after 10 minutes of inactivity, the website is still getting authenticated. I wanted to see a login screen.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius you are right. I'm looking for a way to follow the same flow of the regular logout. In that case I do a "HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");" to remove the cookie client side. Maybe the solution is catching the session status server side and do the same call (SignOut). I'm trying the way filters for a clean solution [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2) or maybe I can just check for a known value in the session. Any suggestion about this?

Comment: @Tonyc for the regular logout just call `SignOutAsync("oidc");` and that's it.

Comment: @TejSoft for IdSrv3 see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363659/identity-server-3-user-session-lifetime)

Comment: @d_f yes, you are right. I added the current code in the question. I do the `SignOutAsync();` for both. So have to find the way to call the `SignOutAsync("oidc");` in case of "main" session expired to remove the cookie of the IDS4 session.

Comment: @Tonyc, that's not the right way. relaying parties should consider the IdP's session as the "main". look: when IdP is a part of your solution, it's not a problem to set it's session "short" and RP's "very short" and each time the local one expires, the RP redirects to IdP for the next one -- that's how silent refresh for web spa-s works. when IdP is not yours (for instance Google), users can disagree when you automatically and mandatory log them out of their Google account.

Comment: @Tonyc look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56327921/always-enter-credentials-without-prompt-login-in-identityserver4), isn't that what you want?

Comment: @d_f I spent some time on your suggestions. Probably what I need is "SSO + Single Logout" as in this article [Single Sign-On and Single Logout](https://auth0.com/docs/sso/current).
But... what happens after some minutes (15 in the real world) of browser inactivity? I would like (for security reasons) to invalidate all sessions and enforce an interactive login at the next click. To reach this result, I thought to check the local session that expires after 15 minutes and do a Single Logout (not on the hypothetical google, only on the IS4). Do you think I'm on the right way?

Comment: I still think it's better to check that 15 minutes inactivity at a central point such as IdSrv. As I understand, you do not have js-driven SPA, but nevertheless nothing prevents you from using silent refresh iframe (you'll need a bit customized one, sending ping only in case of user activity). And yes, that's a good idea to perform single signout every time you fill your user can change.