# Always enter credentials without "prompt=login" in IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

This is similar to [IdentityServer4 Force User to re-enter credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681426/identityserver4-force-user-to-re-enter-credentials), but the solution there says to use `prompt=login` query string in the `/authorize` URL, which works, but also allows for sneaky users to remove it. Also, seeing as I'm not using `.AddOpenIdConnect()` the suggestion to use `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` doesn't apply to me.

So how can we force the user to always enter credentials without relying on the `prompt=login` in the query string?

---

Here's my basic IdentityServer4 setup:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());

    builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseFileServer();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Where my login page only has an "OK" and "Cancel" button (I don't care which user logs on yet, only that authentication was OK or not), and the controller does the following when it is authenticating the user:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(AuthenticateViewModel model, string button)
{
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);

    if (button == "authCancel")
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            await _interaction.GrantConsentAsync(context, ConsentResponse.Denied);
            return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
        }

        return Redirect("~/");
    }

    if (button == "authOk" && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent("provider", "userId", "subjectId", "name"));
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync("subject", "name", new AuthenticationProperties());
            return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
        }
    }

    return Redirect("~/");
}
```

Comment: This is quite simple just override the default cookie scheme and the users will always have to enter credentials despite of url hacking.

Comment: Sounds good. Care to give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option could be to stick to `prompt=login` for all requests or based on  some client setting, or a http header.

It is easy to look into the [default request validator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/314bb5a9f05a296d4ab375e02451ff0a9e9c7bac/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/AuthorizeRequestValidator.cs#L596-L610) and implement your customization like the following:

```cs
public class YourCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator:ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
{
  public Task ValidateAsync(CustomAuthorizeRequestValidationContext context)
  {
    var request = context.Result.ValidatedRequest;    
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Raw["prompted"]))
    {
      request.Raw.Add("prompted", "true");
      request.PromptMode = OidcConstants.PromptModes.Login;
    }
    else if (request.Subject.IsAuthenticated())
    {
      request.PromptMode = OidcConstants.PromptModes.None;
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}
```

and then in your Identityserver startup:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer()
  .AddCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator<YourCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator>();
```

Comment: I tried adding the custom `ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator` from your example, and if it is supposed to force a login on every request to `authorize`, it doesn't quite work. I call `authorize` and the first time it asks me for a login. The second time it doesn't ask for a login and proceeds directly to the `redirect_uri`.

Comment: I tried commenting out the condition, but then it never continues after `/authorize`. I get the login screen, click to log on, then I get the login screen again (repeat ad infinitum)

Comment: You should probably update your code to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead of `.IsMissing()`, but otherwise this seems to do exactly what I want. Thanks :)

Comment: `IsMissing()` is just a convenient wrapper around `return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value);` but probably i stole it from Identityserver internals... will change then

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve desired behaviour by overriding the default cookie scheme that `AddIdentityServer()` registers internally:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()...

services.AddAuthentication("CustomScheme")
    .AddCookie("CustomScheme", options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = ...;
    });
```

Make sure you add the override scheme after `AddIdentityServer()`, the sequence here is important due to the way ASP.Net Core DI works.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it is based on cookie expiry. Which values would usually be enough? I'm guessing 0 seconds is too little and the user will already be logged out again on `auhorize/callback`, and 10 seconds allows quick users to try again before the expiry.

Comment: Just go with something sensible that fits your business problem domain, something I can’t really advise. I used few minutes expiry for a similar requirement like yours in the past.

Comment: I tried this and I can see the followin messages appearing in the log: `CustomScheme was not authenticated. Failure message: Ticket expired`, even with expiry of several minutes. Any idea why?

Comment: It seems like it appears many time when `authorize` is called (probably to check if the user is still signed on), but not after the user has authenticated. It seems a bit unneccessary, though, to fill up the log with many of these log messages. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try 10 minutes (because of clock skew) and give cookie some custom name and check if the correct cookie is then saved upon user signing in.