# Always automatically logged in Microsoft Account

Tags: angular, authentication, oauth, identityserver4

I have an Angular site that integrates with Identity Server (using angular-oauth2-oidc) in order to sign in with Microsoft accounts. However, lately a strange behavior is occuring, without having done any change in the code that is related to logging in or out.

The problem is that if I start the login flow (with `this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow`), I'm redirected to:

```
 https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=b958fc9b-6b36-4bc7-968b-8aa72e7dfc2c&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fsignin-microsoft&state=CfDJ8L7 etc...
```

[image]

But instead of being able to choose an account, **it automatically logs me on** with one of the accounts. I cannot choose another one.

This is occuring in Chrome, but also in Edge for example.

I don't think it has to do with cookies, because when logging out (`oauthService.logOut`) they are cleared:

[image]

If I try this in an incognito window, it am able to pick an account, so then it works.

Does anyone have any idea why it is always logging me in automatically instead of letting me pick an account first?

Comment: Have you checked local storage? By default that is where the token is kept.

Comment: @nullptr.t Nothing to see there either...

Comment: I would add 'prompt=login' to the query parameters of the initial authorize request to avoid any changes in behavior Microsoft might make. 'prompt=login' forces the login prompt so it might mitigate any issue/bug Microsoft may have introduced in their code base

Comment: @Randy Thanks, I will give that a try!!

Comment: FYI: I implemented https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56327921/always-enter-credentials-without-prompt-login-in-identityserver4, hopefully this fixes the strange behaviour...